# django are set operations faster or for loop?

Tags: python, django

Which of the following operations are faster?

Using for loop:

```
 OrgIdChoices = []
 Orgid_used_choices = [(choice["organization_id"])for choice in list(Organization.objects.all().values("organization_id"))]   #Gets used ID's
 OrgIdAvailChoices  = [ "%c%c" % (x, y) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1) for y in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)]  #Gets available ID's
 for i in OrgIdAvailChoices:
      if not i in Orgid_used_choices:
          OrgIdChoices.append((i,i))   #Generates OrgIdAvailChoices which are not in Orgid_used_choices
```

OR using set operation:

```
 OrgIdChoices = []
 Orgid_used_choices = set([(choice["organization_id"])for choice in list(Organization.objects.all().values("organization_id"))])
 OrgIdAvailChoices  = set([ "%c%c" % (x, y) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1) for y in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)])
 OrgChoices = OrgIdAvailChoices - Orgid_used_choices
 for i in OrgChoices:
     OrgIdChoices.append((i,i))
```

Comment: They are both slower than using django's ORM properly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Checking to see if an id is in a list or in a set is the key here - one is faster than the other.

Comment: DJV is right about querying for `used_org_choices`. Now about the `OrgIdAvailChoices` I'm sure `itertools` can aid in your endeavours use them it will be faster..

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [QuerySet API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/), more precisely the `values_list` part (with `flat=True`) and the `distinct()` part. Surely this will be faster than the `values`, extracting the field you want and converting to `list` or `set` approach.

After that a simple approach as generating the set `OrgIdAvailChoices` and `difference_update` with the QuerySet should be quite faster than your proposed one.

Alternatively, inspired by Pannu's comment, an approach with `itertools`:

```
import itertools
import string

filter(
    lambda x: x not in OrgIdAvailChoices,
    [''.join(el) for el in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_uppercase, 2)]
)
```

To tell the truth, I'm not certain if `QuerySet` is actually a set, that is if search in it are logarithmic, but judging by my experience the proper usage of Django's ORM (as described in the beginning of my answer) will bring you the greatest speedup.